# Check char array if contains a specific word

Tags: c

I'm trying to connect in a wifi module.
So i need when i'm receiving \r\nOK\r\n to read my buffer.

Here is my source  file:

```
typedef struct
{
   char ReceivePacket[200];
   char PacketCounter;  
}ModbusRequest_;        

volatile ModbusRequest_ ModbusRequest;
```

This is running inside a void

```
if(strstr(ModbusRequest.ReceivePacket, "\r\nOK\r\n"))
{
   //execute
}
```

But I don't get any result, it doesn't execute my code.
Also these are my includes:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at what contents you _are_ getting in the `ModbusRequest.ReceivePacket` variable?  (i.e. in a log file, or using a break point in debug mode?  Are you certain the string `"\r\nOK\r\n"` is ever really sent?  Try searching for only `"OK\r\n"`

Comment: Yes can see it in printf. But also if i will use this code it works if(ModbusRequest.ReceivePacket[PacketCounter]== 'K' && ModbusRequest.ReceivePacket[PacketCounter-1]== 'O')

Comment: Try string matching with `\r` first and see if that returns a pointer.  If it does, then try matching with `\r\n` and so on.  Let us know what happens.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that your modbus message is null terminated?

Comment: if `K` coincides with `PacketCounter` you will never see the last `\r\n`.  `K` is the last byte read.  Change your search criteria to `\r\nOK`

Comment: What does `PacketCounter` mean? If it is the length of the string in `ReceivePacket`, you are comparing your string with the wrong pattern.... the end of your pattern is "KO", instead of "/r/n"

Comment: Read _[this MODBUS](http://www.modbustools.com/modbus.html)_ link and verify (respond in comments) that it matches (or not) what you are doing, and expecting to see.  From what I am reading, content of responses are context dependent on the corresponding command, but always begin with `:` and end with `\r\n`.  Is this what you are expecting?  BTW, I do not see anywhere that `\r\n` should be embedded in a response prior to the last `\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you all for answers. As i read in string.h library, indeed strstr doesnt include terminal characters. But which fuctions supporting them?